# Execution Timeout Expired of Purchase Receipt Release

Tags: acumatica

i have created a processing screen to create and release Purchase Receipt of Type "Transfer Receipt", without release action it is successfully creating Purchase Receipt, but when if i add release action then am getting error like "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated." I know we can change in web.config file but i don't have access to client's server to do modification.

for release action i have just added  like below

```
receiptGraph.release.Press();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Action in a PXLongOperation:

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate ()
{
   receiptGraph.release.Press();
});
```

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, tried but still getting same issue, you can have a look at code @ https://justpaste.it/7ctft

Comment: You will probably have to wrap more then just that call or set a long operation callback. Can you try to put the long operation on receiptGraph instead of this to see if it changes the behavior?

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, i have changed it but still getting same error, i have updated my code https://justpaste.it/7ctft

Comment: Processing screen should already be using long operation. I think this will require tinkering to resolve. There are many versions of the SetProcessDelegate method. One returns a graph and a single item instead of a list of item I would try to use that instead and perform all operation only using that graph: DataView.SetProcessDelegate<Graph>(delegate (Graph graph, DAC item) {} ))

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, i resolved the issue, i have created new transaction scope only for release acton and now it is working as expected, thanks a lot for your inputs.